# fragment communication unknown error inconvertable types

Tags: android, android-fragments

[MAIN ACTIVITY.JAVA][FragmentA.java
[Fragmentb.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG6r4.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG6r4.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can just paste your code into the text area of your question and use the "code format" button to format it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are extending `FragmentB` from `Fragment`. Also, the package names for Fragments do not match. Check that if you are importing the correct package for `Fragment`, it should be `android.app.Fragment` not `com.company.lenovo.communication.FragmentA.` Verify package names for all your files.